# send / communicate variables between study and strategy

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

not sure if this is possible but I'd like to do the following:

- define several global variables within multiple studies (indicators)
- pass/source/target those global variables within my strategy

I've seen that you can "reference" up to one study within a strategy but can't seem to find any other information for either multiple references or passing variable values between studies (study) and strategies (strategy).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to incorporate the code from the other indicators into your strategy as you can only use one external input.

Answer (score 0):

you can using connnector look at this as example.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/2lGyzYkC-Ultimate-Strategy-Template/